# How do I show a Progress Indicator when loading data in StreamBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter

Consider I have this

```
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: myBloc.productList,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot != null) {
                  if (snapshot.data.length > 0) {
                    return buildProductList(snapshot);
                  }
                  else if (snapshot.data.length==0){
                    return Center(child: Text('No Data'));
                  }
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return ErrorScreen(errMessage: snapshot.error.toString());
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

At first progress indicator will work fine but when data is not found and once 'No Data' gets displayed then the progress indicator never appears again.

How to show progress indicator while loading data only. And show no data when no data and show data when there is data?

This is how the bloc part

```
  final _fetcher = BehaviorSubject<List<Product>>();
  Observable<List<Product>> get productList => _fetcher.stream;
```

Just fetch data from RESTAPI then put it in the List

```
List<Product> product = await _repository.fetchProduct().catchError((err) => _fetcher.addError(err));

_fetcher.sink.add(product);
```

Comment: How did you implement the productList stream in the BLoC?

Comment: Using stream and sink. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.data != null` are literally the exact same (`hasData` calls `data != null` internally). I actually misread your code there, but `snapshot` will never be `null`. Thus you can drop it anyway.

The problem here is that you have a misunderstanding of how `Stream`'s work. The stream **will not** push an update if you are currently adding a `product`. How would it know when to do that anyway? It will only update if you call `add` on it and in that case the `data` will not be `null`. Hence, there is no progress indicator.

You can easily fix that by adding `null` when loading:

```
_fetcher.sink.add(null); // to show progress indicator

List<Product> product = await _repository.fetchProduct().catchError((err) => _fetcher.addError(err));

_fetcher.sink.add(product); // to show data
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried adding _fecther.sink.add(null) I guess it was a wrong one

Comment: Sorry _fetcher.sink.add(null) also works maybe hotreload issue when I first tried it

Answer (score 5):

`snapshot.connectionState` can tell if your data is still loading...

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was quite feasible before Dart moved on to null safety but now, it might be a bit uncomfortable if you have to change your stream type to `T?` just to be able to pass null in these cases. So, I prefer another approach now. I simply create a special "error":

```
class StreamBuilderProgress extends Error {}
```

and pass this to the list when the time comes:

```
list.addError(StreamBuilderProgress());
```

and make sure that I return the progress indicator whenever `snapshot.hasError && snapshot.error is StreamBuilderProgress`.

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamBuilder<List<Room>>(
        stream: roomsSource.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  print("loading data");
            }else if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty){
                  print("no data");
            }else if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty){
                  print("has data");
            }else {
                  print("error");
            }
        }
)
```